# Ubuntu 12.04 Cannot get Epson L210 to work with Scanner (Xsane)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, scanner

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed. I just bought an Epson L210 print/copy/scanner.

I can use it to print, but cannot get it to work with Xsane or Simple Scan.

I downloaded the Linux driver for this from Epson (http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) and installed it using the Ubuntu Software Center.

The version I installed was iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb.

What happens when I click Xsane is I get this message: Failed to open device...

I have also tried to modify the backend in terminal using the procedure on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Scanners, but no dice.

I was able to scan with Xsane with my previous brother printer.

Although I have been using Ubuntu for more than 3 years I am not that technically adept. If anyone can offer any help, please bear that in mind--I will need baby steps! Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Not 5 minutes after posting this I restarted my computer and I can now use Xsane. I had restarted several times before, so I am not sure what I did to make it work this time. Thanks to anyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 2):

*Answer created by the OP ([@user148966](https://askubuntu.com/users/148966/user148966)) in [the comment above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280920/ubuntu-12-04-cannot-get-epson-l210-to-work-with-scanner-xsane#comment353024_280920):*

> Not 5 minutes after posting this I restarted my computer and I can now
>   use Xsane. I had restarted several times before, s

Comment: Since restarting the computer fixed it mysteriously (and restarting is not a general solution--it had not worked before), this question should actually just be closed as *too localized*. It won't help anyone because whatever actually fixed the problem is unknown.